# Default an unbound text box on a form to a particular date

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form called "Main Menu" with two unbound text boxes that are labeled "EffBegDate" and "EffEndDate".

This date range is used in various queries that are run via command buttons on the same form.

How do I get these text boxes to default to specific dates?  I realize this probably requires VBA code, but I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.  The user should still be able to override the default values if desired.

Comment: June7 - Yes, I tried the DefaultValue property but it didn't populate the text box.  And I don't want to restrict users to a particular set of dates.  I'm just looking to pre-populate the standard values to streamline the process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DefaultValue property? Also set the Format property to a date format. Could also probably take advantage of ValidationRule and ValidationText properties to make sure the EffEndDate is greater than EffBegDate.

If you want to restrict users to a specific set of dates, perhaps values existing in a dataset, use a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I used the "On Got Focus" property, used the "Code Builder" option and entered the following code:

```
[Forms]![Main Menu]![EffBegDate] = "01/01/2017"
```

Now whenever the focus is on the "EffBegDate" text box, it autopopulates the date as 01/01/2017.  I can still override the date to whatever I want.